# Add ListCreateAPIView-class to router

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I add a ListCreateAPIView to the router urls?

Normally I do like:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'busses', BusViewSet)
```

but now I have:

```
class CarList(generics.ListCreateAPIView): ...
```

I added it to the urlpatterns for now:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
url(r'^carts/', CarList.as_view(model=Car), name='cars'),
```

and I would like to add this Cars-view (which is working as intended if I call the url manually!) to the router, so it's in the overview page!

So: It works as it is, but I have to manually enter the url, it's not in the overview-page of the API.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

The reason is why a `ViewSet` classes work with a router is a `GenericViewSet` which has a `ViewSetMixin` in a bases.
`ViewSetMixin`  override `as_view()` method  so that it takes an `actions` keyword that performs the binding of HTTP methods to actions on the Resource and router can build a map for action-method.
You can solve it by simple adding that mixin in a class bases:

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ViewSetMixin

class CarList(ViewSetMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView)
    ....
```

But it is not clear solution because `ListCreateAPIView` and `ModelViewSet` it is just an empty classes with a bunch of mixins in a bases. So you always can build you own `ViewSet` with a methods you need.
For example, here the code of `ListCreateAPIView`:

```
class ListCreateAPIView(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                    GenericAPIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And here the `ModelViewSet`:

```
class ModelViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
               mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
               mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
               mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
               mixins.ListModelMixin,
               GenericViewSet):

    pass
```

Notice a same mixins `ListModelMixin` and `CreateModelMixin` there is only difference in `GenericViewSet` and `GenericAPIView`.
`GenericAPIView` use method names and call an actions inside them. `GenericViewSet` instead use actions and map them to methods.
Here the `ViewSet` with methods you need:

```
class ListCreateViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                    GenericViewSet):   

    queryset_class = ..
    serializer_class = ..
```

Now it will work with a router and you can override `list` and `create` methods if you need a special behavior.